# According to Catholic Scholars, what did the original text of Agnus Dei read as?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, old-testament, atonement

We read in Leviticus 16: 7-10 :

> He shall take the two goats and set them before the Lord at the entrance of the tent of meeting;   and Aaron shall cast lots on the two goats, one lot for the Lord and the other lot for Azazel. Aaron shall present the goat on which the lot fell for the Lord, and offer it as a sin offering;   but the goat on which the lot fell for Azazel shall be presented alive before the Lord to make atonement over it, that it may be sent away into the wilderness to Azazel.

So, we have the Agnus Dei among our daily prayers.  The Syrian custom of a chant addressed to the Lamb of God was introduced into the Roman Rite Mass by Pope Sergius I (687–701){Courtesy: Wikipedia}. The Agnus Dei in the present form goes like "Lamb of God who **takes away** the sins of the world... ".

Interestingly,  to this day, the chant of Agnus Dei which accompanies the Vesper hymns of various feasts in Syro Malabar Catholic rite  of Southern India( which has had many of its traditional  hymns directly translated from Syriac) roughly translates into English as " Lamb of God **who is burdened** with the sins of the world.."". That version appears to have done more justice to Leviticus  16:10  where the lamb, loaded with the sins of Israel, was sent to the wilderness to die .

My question, therefore is: According to Catholic Scholars, what did the original text of Agnus Dei read as?